# Java: Is there a way to make a parent interface's default methods override a parent class's methods automatically in a child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a class that extends another class and implements an interface. The parent interface has a default method with the same signature as a method in the parent class, like below.

```java
class ParentClass {
    public void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Class method called");
    }
}

interface ParentInterface {
    default void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("Interface method called");
    }
}

class Child extends ParentClass implements ParentInterface {

}
```

At the moment, when `doSomething()` is called on an instance of the `Child` class, the version of the method from the parent class is run (Printing `"Class method called"`). However, I want the `Child` class to use the version of the method defined in the parent interface (Printing `"Interface method called"`).

One way to do this is to override the `doSomething()` in the `Child` class and tell it to choose `ParentInterface.super.doSomething()` like so:

```java
class Child extends ParentClass implements ParentInterface {
    public void doSomething() {
        ParentInterface.super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I have a lot of methods in `ParentInterface` and a lot of classes that implement `ParentInterface` and extend various classes that have their own version of the methods of `ParentInterface`. I've been very confused by some bugs because I was assuming a method call was going to `ParentInterface` when it was actually going to the parent class. In all cases, I would prefer if the default methods defined in the interface were always chosen over their corresponding methods from the class.

Is there some way that I can make my child classes default to using `ParentInterface`'s methods without having to override each conflicting method in the child class?

Comment: I think you’re complicating things for yourself. Try to rethink the structure of your code. Avoid inheriting behavior. Try to use composition instead. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49002/11451

Comment: No, the JLS clearly states that an implementation inherited from a parent class will always "win" over a default interface methods. That's also why default methods for `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` aren't possible.

Comment: You might reasonably make a new subtype of ParentClass that is a subinterface of ParentInterface, do all the super. logic there, and subclass that instead of ParentClass.